# Problem with await in my register function using React with Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, async-await, firebase-authentication

**This is my register function:**

```
register : async (email: string, password: string) => {
        try {
            const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
            const user = userCredential.user;

            if (user) {
                await set(ref(database, `users/${user.uid}`), {
                    email: user.email
                });
                return true;
            }
        } catch (error : any) {
            switch (error.code) {
                case "auth/email-already-in-use":
                    alert("Tento email je už používaný někým jiným.");
                    break;
                case "auth/invalid-email":
                    alert("Špatně zadaný email. Email musí být v tomto formátu: jan@novotny.cz");
                    break;
                case "auth/weak-password":
                    alert("Slabé heslo. Vyber si silnější heslo.");
                    break;
                case "auth/network-request-failed":
                    alert("Chyba v síti. Prosím zkuste to znovu později.");
                    break;
                default:
                    alert("Nečekaný error :c : " + error.message);
            }
            return false;
        }
    },
```

**And this is my page where i use the registration:**

```
const Login: NextPage = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [createUser] = useCreateUserMutationMutation();
  const router = useRouter();
  const firestore = getFirestore();
  const usersRef = collection(firestore, 'users');

  const isUsernameUsed = async (username: any) => {
    const usernameQuery = query(usersRef, where("username", "==", username));
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(usernameQuery);
    return querySnapshot; 
  }

  const handleForm = async (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const usernameResult = await isUsernameUsed(username);
    const userData = usernameResult.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
    const registerResult = await authUtils.register(email, password); 

    if(registerResult && userData.length == 0) {
      createUser({ variables: { email, username } });
      router.push('/login');
    }

    if(userData.length > 0)
      alert("Toto jméno je už používané. Zvolte si jiné.");
  };

  const buttonHover = {
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: customColors.lightBackground,
      color: customColors.black
    },
  };

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={mainTheme}>
      <Header></Header>
      <Box
        width="100vw"
        height="100vh"
        top={0}
        sx={{ bgcolor: customColors.white, position: 'absolute', zIndex: -1 }}
      >
        <Container
          component="main"
          maxWidth="xs"
          sx={{ pb: '2  5px', border: '2px solid black', borderRadius: '20px', mt: '10%' }}
        >
          <Box
            sx={{
              padding: '25px 0',
              display: 'flex',
              flexDirection: 'column',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}
          >
            <Avatar sx={{ m: 1, bgcolor: customColors.lightBackground }}>
              <LockOutlinedIcon />
            </Avatar>
            <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
              Registrace
            </Typography>
            <Box
              component="form"
              onSubmit={handleForm}
              noValidate
              sx={{ mt: 1 }}
            >
              <TextField
                margin="normal"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="username"
                label="Zadejte vaši přezdívku"
                name="username"
                autoFocus
                color="info"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  const { value } = e.target;
                  setUsername(value);
                }}
              />
              <TextField
                margin="normal"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="email"
                label="Zadejte email adresu"
                name="email"
                autoComplete="email"
                autoFocus
                color="info"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  const { value } = e.target;
                  setEmail(value);
                }}
              />
              <TextField
                margin="normal"
                required
                fullWidth
                name="password"
                label="Zadejte heslo"
                type="password"
                id="password"
                autoComplete="current-password"
                color="info"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  const { value } = e.target;
                  setPassword(value);
                }}
              />
              <Button
                type="submit"
                fullWidth
                variant="contained"
                sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2, backgroundColor: customColors.black, color: customColors.white, ...buttonHover }}
              >
                Registrovat se
              </Button>
              <Grid container>
                <Grid item>
                  <Link component={NextLink} href="/login" variant="body2" sx={{ color: customColors.black, textDecorationColor: customColors.black }}>
                    Už máte účet?
                  </Link>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </Box>
          </Box>
        </Container>
      </Box>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

And im having a problem when i submit the form the **handleForm** function starts and it always got stuck on the line with **registerResult**, so i inspected the register function itself and found out that it gets stuck on this:

```
await set(ref(database, `users/${user.uid}`), {
                    email: user.email
                });
```

Oh and also the set creates the user in the realtime database, but after that it just stops.

I tried everything i could and i dont know what to do more please help me.

I tried everything and nothing worked.

Comment: Code doesn't typically get stuck. If the `set(ref(...))` call doesn't complete, most likely it raises an error. I recommend putting a `console.error(error)` statement in the `catch (error : any) {` and seeing what it outputs.

Comment: I tried that already it just doesnt return anything no error.

Comment: Hmm... the code looks fine, so without an error or other debugging information I'm not sure what could be goign wrong. Hopefully somebody else spots the problem.